# I have an error.Where am I going Wrong?The question is that all child cases should be closed then and only then parent can change status

Tags: apex, trigger

> Status: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException:
> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL  without querying the requested
> field: Case.ParentId Class.StatusTriggerHandler.StatusHandler: line
> 25, column 1 Trigger.Status: line 12, column 1

```
trigger Status on Case (before update)
{
    
    //Write the code in such a way that it can handle multiple data
    Case caseStatusBeforeChange = Trigger.old[0];
    Case caseStatusAfterChange = Trigger.new[0];
    System.debug('Old Status value =' +caseStatusBeforeChange);
    System.debug('New Status value =' +caseStatusAfterChange);
    
    if(caseStatusBeforeChange.id == caseStatusAfterChange.id && caseStatusBeforeChange.Status != caseStatusAfterChange.Status)
    {
        StatusTriggerHandler.StatusHandler(Trigger.new);
    }
    else
    {
            
    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        if(Trigger.isBefore)
        {
            StatusTriggerHandler.StatusHandler(Trigger.new); 
        }
        
    }
}
```

```java
public class StatusTriggerHandler
{
    public static void StatusHandler(List<Case> newcaseList)
    {
        //Storing all id's in a set
        Set<Id> caseIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        for(case c : newcaseList)
        {
            caseIdSet.add(c.Id);
        }
        System.debug('Here is =' + caseIdSet); 
        //we got our case id 00001034 
        System.debug('Here is Newcase List' + newcaseList);
      
        
        // case List  
        List <Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIdSet];

        // Child Case List.
        List <Case> caseChildList = [SELECT Id,Status FROM case WHERE ParentId IN :newcaseList];
        Map<Id,Boolean> caseMap = new Map<Id,Boolean>();
        Map<Id,List<Case>> caseParentToCaseChildMap = new Map<Id,List<Case>>();
           
        for(Case case1 : [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE ParentId IN :newCaseList]) {
            if(caseParentToCaseChildMap.containsKey(case1.ParentId) ) {
                List<Case> CaseList1 = caseParentToCaseChildMap.get(case1.ParentId);
                CaseList1.add(case1);
                caseParentToCaseChildMap.put(case1.ParentId, CaseList1);
            } else {
                caseParentToCaseChildMap.put(case1.ParentId, new List<Case> {Case1});
            }
        }
        
        for(Id caseId:caseParentToCaseChildMap.keySet())
        {
            
            List<String> flagList = new List<String>();
            
            for(Case case2:  caseParentToCaseChildMap.get(caseId))
            {
               
                    if(case2.Status == 'Close'){
                        flagList.add('true');
                    }
                    else{
                        flagList.add('false');
                    }
                }   
            
            if(!flagList.contains('false')){
                 caseMap.put(caseId,true);
            }
            else{
                 caseMap.put(caseId,false);
            }
        
        }
        //List<Case> updatedCaseList = new List<Case>();
        //List<Case>errorCaseList = new List<Case>();
        if(caseMap.size() > 0){
            for(Case case3 : caseList){
                if(caseMap.containsKey(case3.Id) == true)
                {
                    if(CaseMap.get(case3.id) == True){
                        ((Case)Trigger.newMap.get(case3.Id)).Status = 'Close';
                    }
                    else{
                        // ((Case)Trigger.newMap.get(case3.Id)).
                        case3.addError('Child record is not Close');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: You are getting this error because you are using ParentId but haven't retrieved using SOQL. So add ParentId in SOQL that will solve this error

Answer (score 3):

The error is giving you pretty clear information here, you just need to take a little time to read it.

Taking the important part of it

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Case.ParentId

So you're trying to use `<case variable>.ParentId` somewhere. The stack trace tells you this is line 25. Counting out the lines, that brings you to

```
if(caseParentToCaseChildMap.containsKey(case1.ParentId))
```

Yep, you certainly are using `ParentId`. Are you actually querying for it though? Let's look just a line upwards.

```
for(Case case1 : [SELECT Id, Status FROM Case WHERE ParentId IN :newCaseList]) {
```

Nope, you don't have `ParentId` in the `SELECT` clause. That means that you aren't querying that field, which in turn means that you can't use that field. `ParentId` does appear in a filter (i.e. a part of the `WHERE` clause, i.e. `ParentId IN :newCaseList`), but to be able to read/access `ParentId` outside of the query, it needs to appear in the `SELECT` clause.

Note that I specifically said if you want to *read* the `ParentId` field. If you were trying to write/set the `ParentId` field, you don't need to query for it.

```java
Account a1 = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
Account a2 = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id != :a1.Id LIMIT 1];

// we haven't queried the field before trying to read it
// this will result in an error
Id parentId = a1.ParentId;

// we can set fields without having queried them
a1.ParentId = a2.Id;

// after setting a field, we can read/access the value
// even if we didn't initially query for it
Id parentId2 = a1.ParentId;
```

Another way to think about it is in terms of where `a1.ParentId` is in the expression. Is it to the left of the `=` (i.e. an l-value) or to the right (i.e. an r-value)?
We don't need to query for a field to use it as an l-value
We do need to query for a field to use it as an r-value

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the error message. You're referring to fields you're not explicitly retrieving/

Change your SOQL from

`SELECT Id, Status FROM Case`

to

`SELECT ID, Status, ParentID FROM Case`

Then you should be ok. Also this is something that would be well suited for doing in a FLOW rather than APEX.